# How to auto-wire constructors AND properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

The following example did not behave as expected. How can I auto-wire the constructor AND properties? I can create my Wizard bean with a robe or a wand, but not both (without explicit wiring).

Here's the code:

```
public static class Wizard {

    private final Robe robe;
    private Wand wand;

    public Wizard() { robe = null; }

    public Wizard(final Robe robe) { this.robe = robe; }

    public void setWand(final Wand wand) { this.wand = wand; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", robe = " + robe + ", wand = " + wand;
    }
}

public static class Wand { }

public static class Robe { }
```

Here are my common bean definitions:

```
<bean id="robe" class="org.hoipolloi.Foo.Robe" />
<bean id="wand" class="org.hoipolloi.Foo.Wand" />
```

Now, if I configure wizard as such:

```
<bean id="wizard" class="org.hoipolloi.Foo.Wizard" autowire="byType" />
```

The robe is never populated:

```
// Prints org.hoipolloi.Foo$Wizard@7c7e7c7e, robe = null, wand = org.hoipolloi.Foo$Wand@72887288
System.out.println(ctx.getBean("wizard"));
```

If I switch to auto-wiring by constructor:

```
<bean id="wizard" class="org.hoipolloi.Foo.Wizard" autowire="constructor" />
```

Then my wizard has no wand:

```
// Prints org.hoipolloi.Foo$Wizard@18381838, robe = org.hoipolloi.Foo$Robe@2cec2cec, wand = null
System.out.println(ctx.getBean("wizard"));
```

Is there any way of auto-wiring the wizard bean so he has both robe AND wand (i.e. both constructor args and properties are wired)?

EDIT: I should note, 'byName' behaves the same as 'byType' i.e. robe is null.

Comment: Have you tried setting an @Autowired annotation on your constructor and setter?

Comment: Interesting - instead of a solution I found a strong vote against autowiring in [Twelve Best Practices for Spring XML Configurations](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/01/25/spring-xml-configuration-best-practices.html)

Comment: @Andreas yes, but that's from 2006. A lot has changed since then!

Comment: @Sean - the reason for the *downvote* in that article is that *xml based* autowiring increases complexity and adds confusion. *That* hasn't been changed. Annotation based autowiring is different here.

Comment: @Andreas fair enough ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Either make setters for both, or include both in the constructor.

You can also use annotations instead of automatic autowiring.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working through 'Spring in Action' and haven't got to the annotations part yet. I'll try them out soon.